# Java get MAXIMIZED state window size

Tags: java, window, fullscreen, noborder

I am developing a multi platform game and I wanted to make a full-screen non bordered window and this is where I got into a problem for LINUX operating system.

For WINDOWS system I was using **Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()** method to get complete SCREEN SIZE and it worked fine, but for LINUX my screen was a bit wider and higher due to LINUX BARS.

*SOLUTION in my answer bellow

Comment: This site works on a Question and answer format. If you have solved this problem, and it hasn't been asked before on the site, please phrase the problem as a question and then answer it in the normal fashion below.

Comment: @AdiBradfield Okay, next time I will think about it :( thank you for informing me...

Comment: @AdiBradfield done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*SOLUTION
After many hours of browsing the internet I already found the solution to get size of the window when its in MAXIMIZED state (Like you press maximize square on frame) and gives you MAXIMUM allowed size of the window paying attention on all OPERATING SYSTEM bars.
Here is the method: **GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()**

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/).  This will give your program full access to the whole screen, removing any need for you to be concerned about task/dock bars and the like

Or you could do something like

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
Rectangle bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());

Rectangle safeBounds = new Rectangle(bounds);
safeBounds.x += insets.left;
safeBounds.y += insets.top;
safeBounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
safeBounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
```

Essentially all this does is gets the screen bounds (x/y and width/height), the screens insets for the device and updates the screen bounds to take into consideration things like the task bar and other system resources.

You could also simply try using something like [`Frame#setExtendedState`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) which will allow you to put the window into `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` and let it do the work for you

Comment: I appreciate all help about this topic, but my software have to allow users to set their desired window size plus automatically fullscreen and also allow them to decide if bordered or non bordered. It was very hard to find the right answer I was looking for and I am very happy I already found it. ;)